# Array of Structs (expected expression error) C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have the following code. I am trying to populate an array with a deck of cards, and I keep encountering the same error "expected expression error" no matter how I code the loops to populate the array.

Can anybody see where I'm going wrong. I think its something painfully simple, that I, who am new to C++, am just missing.

Thanks!!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct playingCard{
    char suit; // heart (1), club (2), spade (3), diamond (4)
    int value; // 1 to 13 (ace is LOW)

};

void printArray(playingCard playingCardArray[], int size){
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i ++){
        cout << playingCardArray[i].suit << ":\t" << playingCardArray[i].value << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{

    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 52;
    playingCard playingCardArray[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int i = 1;
    int suitLoop = 1;
    while (suitLoop == 1){
        for (int valueLoop = 1; valueLoop <= 13; valueLoop++){
            playingCardArray[i] = {suitLoop, valueLoop},
        }
     }

    printArray(playingCardArray, ARRAY_SIZE);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `playingCardArray[i] = {suitLoop, valueLoop},` should end with `;` not a comma. Did your error message not mention the line the error was on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve your compilation issue change you inner `for` loop like this:

```
for (int valueLoop = 1; valueLoop <= 13; valueLoop++){
    playingCardArray[i].suit = suitLoop;
    playingCardArray[i].value = valueLoop;
}
```

Other than compilation your code also has **Infinite loop** , to resolve this you need to change your `main` somewhat like this:

```
int main()
{
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 52;
    playingCard playingCardArray[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int i = 1;
    int suitLoop = 0;
    while (suitLoop < ARRAY_SIZE){
        for (int valueLoop = 1; valueLoop <= 13; valueLoop++){
            playingCardArray[suitLoop].suit = (suitLoop/13 + 1);
            playingCardArray[suitLoop++].value = valueLoop;
        }
     }

    printArray(playingCardArray, ARRAY_SIZE);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ehm, your "fix" still has an infinite loop. You didn't fix it.

Comment: Can you please point out where..

Comment: Personally, I prefer a style where the index variable is the same, and the suitLoop++ is on a separate line.  Compiler will generate the same code, but it's more obvious to the human reader.  I don't see any infinite loop, so up voted.

Comment: @Learner: Oh, no, never mind, missed your `suitLoop++`. That's really well hidden. A great reason not to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Exchanging the comma with a semicolon at the end of `playingCardArray[i] = {suitLoop, valueLoop},` solves the problem.